# Chat application buddies presence status view refresh on response design?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

What is the optimized way of displaying friends presence status in a table cell with custom `div`s? Order of display shall be *Online* and then *Offline* friends sorted alphabetically.

One crude way is to send an ajax request and refresh/redraw the whole table of friends (except the rest of page) once the browser receives server response based on the sorted data structure. But I think there should be some other better optimized way too which may target specific div's, rearranging them or whatever. Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question, you may want to add some markup to your question to make it clearer and more attractable (`**bold**, *italics*`, paragraphs). Read about it in the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the optimized way of displaying friends presence status in a table cell with custom divs?

If you want to display *lists* of friends, why not use `UL`/`LI` elements instead of meaningless `DIV`?

> Order of display shall be Online and then Offline friends sorted alphabetically.

Well, you can re-arrange existing DOM element by using `appendChild`/`insertBefore` or the like (or jQuery’s `append`/`prepend` f.e.) – that will automatically remove the element from it’s current parent node before inserting it at the target position.

So to reassign an element from on element `#online` into `#offline` would be simple – but since you want alphabetic ordering as well, you will have to figure out the position of the element to insert before/after beforehand.

But if these lists won’t grow *too* big, then I think I’d rather avoid that, and just replace the whole lists with the new (sorted) data received from the server … because I’m not sure if looping through the other elements to figure out the correctly sorted insert position will be actually cheaper than having the browser just rebuild the whole stuff in one go.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, even I think that way and that's how my code is running presently. I'll accept this unless got a better way. BTW for the first point I meant using div's inside the table rows.